# Deploying a ASP.NET MVC 5 Application in Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a ASP.NET MVC5 Solution which uses jQuery, Slickgrid, jQuery UI, Bootstrap. 
The bundling is working fine in my local system as well as in a VM where I have deployed in Windows Server 2008 R2 after publishing the solution in File System Mode.

This is the correct formatting. 
[image]

But after I do the same filesystem deployment onto to Windows Server 2012 R2. 
The formatting is broken and it appears like this.

[image]

Similar other javascript plugins are also failing.

Datepicker based on bootstrap does not pop out anything on click.

The Grids loading with the help of slickgrid is also failing to load anything.

[image]

When Debug the web pages loaded on the two environments and go to the debugger in IE. This is what I observe.

In Windows Server 2008 R2:

[image]

In Windows Server 2012 R2:

[image]

Any pointers regarding the deployment process or the salient features of deploying on Windows Server 2012 R2 would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that your scripts are deployed correctly and are working after deployment?

Comment: Can you please open up the browsers development tools > go to the Console and tell us about any error messages? (Usually it's F12 to access that).

Comment: I have added the output I see in the debugger after deploying same solution in both environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out!

The issue was the site was not added to trusted sites in the internet explorer and hence it was not allowing my Javascript to be rendered!

There are two possible solutions.

1. Ask your users to add this to the trusted sites to continue.

OR

2. Implement an SSL Based HTTPS site.